# Error while trying to open 'Love2d' game engine

Tags: lua, path, game-engine, love2d

I'm trying to open a game with *Love2D* and the following error occurs:

> Error
>
> boot.lua:577: Cannot load game at path
>   '/home/panali/Desktop/Lua.love/main.lua'. Make sure a folder exists at
>   the specified path.
>
> Traceback
>
> [C]: in function 'error'
>   [C]: in function 'xpcall'
>   [C]: in function 'xpcall'

Can anyone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error is pretty self-explainatory. "make sure a folder exists at the specified path". did you make sure it exists? Are you using Linux?

Comment: Yes I'm using linux ubuntu 20.04 and the folder already exists

Comment: did you try to provide the path without the filename main.lua? in the examples the only provide a path. .love is the ending for packaged love games is it not? you use that as a folder?

Comment: Yes i tried that too!

Comment: adding to your post what you have tried would save us both time ;)

Comment: so you have a `/home/panali/Desktop/Lua.love/main.lua` and you run `love /home/panali/Desktop/Lua.love/` ?  Did you try to not have a . in your folder name?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/panali/Desktop/Lua.love/main.lua`

Answer (score 9):

had the same issue, resolved this by pointing folder instead filename:

```
love ./
```

instead of

```
love main.lua
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to open the folder instead of lua file

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you're still looking at this, the error is that you cant open a main.lua directly, it has to be in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can't just give the location of the file, you need to give to location of the folder. try putting `main.lua` inside a folder and then run the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag the folder to the love icon instead of dragging the main.lua file to the love icon it works.

Comment: An answer is not a really good place to ask a related question (most likely noone is going to respond, or if someone will, it will be considered off-topic). I recommend you to ask it as a new question (after doing some research, chances are it was already asked and answered before)

Answer (score -1):

The folder cant have a space in it. It took me an hour to find this out myself.

Comment: The question tells you the path the asker tried, and it already doesn't contain a space.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).